# Most efficient way to sort key-value pair in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I have an array (no need for resizing) of key-value pairs. The keys are 64-bit uint, values can be 32-bit.

What is the most efficient way to get this pair sorted? I have searched the web but most documentation are only concerned about getting a sorted array of keys. If the method only sort the keys, then search for the corresponding values one by one, then the performance may be unsatisfactory.

For example, keysSortedByValue from NSDictionary will give me an array of keys ordered using their values, but I also need that array of sorted values.

Is there a method in objective-c that returns an array of sorted keys AND corresponding values?

Something that if I input:

```
uint64  *keys_in;         // e.g., [8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]
uint32  *values_in;       // e.g., [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

And give me the following in a single step:

```
keys_out            <-- [0, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
values_out          <-- [5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 0, 6]
```

Comment: " the keys while moving the values along with the keys". Could you give us a sample of your array? Because I think it's unclear. You seem to NSDictionary vocabulary and at the same time the "moving along" seems like they aren't synced. I think the way you constructed your array should be changed.

Comment: If they are meant to be synched, they should be in a single array, not in two arrays. Also, do you need C-Array, or you can use `NSArray`?

Comment: @Larme Yeah I guess I wasn't clear enough. Edited by question, hopefully its better now. NSArray is fine btw.

Answer (score 0):

These two arrays are meant to be synched. So you shouldn't use two arrays.
What if at some point you want to remove one? You need to remove it on the second one too. If one changes the other one needs to change. That's a good way to have wrong elements at the end.

Instead, create a custom object:

```
@interface CustomObject : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) uint64 keyIn;
@property (nonatomic, assign) uint32 valueIn;
-(id)initWithKey:(uint64)key andValue:(uint32)value;
@end

@implementation CustomObject
-(id)initWithKey:(uint64)key andValue:(uint32)value
{

    if (self)
    {
        _keyIn = key;
        _valueIn = valueIn;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

For the first one in your "list":

```
CustomObject *first = [[CustomObject alloc] initWithKey:8 andValue:0];
```

Suppose that now we have an `NSArray` of `CustomObjects`:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [arrayUnsorted sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(CustomObject * _Nonnull obj1, CustomObject * _Nonnull obj2) {
        uint64 key1 = [obj1 keyIn];
        uint64 key2 = [obj2 keyIn];
        return [@(key1) compare:@(key2)];
    }];
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you!!